How can I make the Shadcn/UI ScrollArea take full width and add a scroll when the content overflows?
I'm working on a Nextjs project with shadcn/ui where I have a ScrollArea component that's supposed to take the full width of its container and add a horizontal scroll bar when the content overflows. Inside this ScrollArea, I have a Table component that's overflowing its container instead of causing the ScrollArea to scroll.
<div className=" w-full">
  {/* FIXME Fix horizontal scroll  */}
  <ScrollArea className=" w-full overflow-x-auto ">
    <div className="w-full whitespace-nowrap">
      <Table className="relative min-w-full">
        {/* ... rest of the table code ... */}
      </Table>
    </div>
  </ScrollArea>
</div>

This is where i am importing it
<div className="mx-auto max-w-6xl">
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between px-2 py-5 md:px-4 md:py-10">
        <h1 className=" text-2xl font-semibold">Tasks</h1>
        <AddTaskButton id={params.id} />
      </div>
      <TasksTable data={transformedData!} columns={columns} />
    </div>

I also have a ScrollArea in layout.tsx
 <section className=" flex h-full flex-row overflow-clip">
      <Sidebar id={params.id} />
      <ScrollArea className=" h-full w-full p-4">{children}</ScrollArea>
    </section>

I've set white-space: nowrap; on the Table to prevent text from wrapping to the next line.
Still, the Table is still overflowing the ScrollArea instead of causing it to scroll.
Overflowing content

I found a little trick to make it fill the parent width.
<div className="flex">
    <ScrollArea type="always" className="w-1 flex-1">
        <div className="flex gap-2 pb-4">{...your array of elements...}</div>
        <ScrollBar orientation="horizontal" className="w-full" />
    </ScrollArea>
</div>

Trick is to set both flex-1 and a random width (I set w-1) to the ScrollArea

This worked like a charm. Also in bonus it automatically resizes the container when say the sidebar is expanded.

You need to update your first block of code as bellow:
<div className=" w-full">
  {/* FIXME Fix horizontal scroll  */}
  <ScrollArea className=" w-full overflow-x-auto ">
    <div className="w-full whitespace-nowrap">
      <Table className="relative min-w-full">
        {/* ... rest of the table code ... */}
      </Table>
    </div>
    <ScrollBar orientation="horizontal" />
  </ScrollArea>
</div>

Changes:

Added a second Scrollbar with an orientation prop to enable horizontal scrolling.

You can learn more here

Yes i tried that but the content still overflows with no scrolling
